# Multiple Selections

Tags: jsp, jsf, jsf-1.2, large-data

I using JSF 1.2 and working with a set of about 240 items that I would like my user to select either as one, some, or all.  My best design intention is a

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{EventUnitTesting.event}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="-- select one --" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{EventUnitTesting.events}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

in which the user can designate one, some, or all the items through a

```
<h:commandButton value="Select"
        action="#{EventUnitTesting.select}" />
```

that adds each selected item into a `java.util.List`

This approach works well for one or some but not necessarily all.  I thought of using `h:selectManyCheckbox` but I don't think that is very user friendly either for a set of 240 items.

Any recommendations for displaying a selectable large set of data but easier to work with when choosing one, some, or all data in JSF 1.2?

Comment: I think you are looking for https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-multiple-select-dropdown-box-example/

Comment: You are not going to win this war by changing the component. Offering a user 240 options is never going to work. Best thing IMO is to categorize your options into smaller groups.